# Using the word "Influential"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, adjectives

A Japanese friend asked me this:

> When I want to say that someone has influenced me, I can say "influenced by". When I am skeptical of someone or doubtful of someone, I can say, "skeptical of" and "doubtful of". Since "doubtful" and "skeptical" are both adjectives, would it be possible for me to say "I am influential of you"? I think you can because the word "influential" is an adjective."

Basically he is trying to ask me if "I am influenced by you" is the same as "I am influential of you". Although I have never really heard the latter phrase before, my friend seems to have a point with this one.

Even if it's not heard in professional writings or speech, do you think it could be used in a colloquial way?

Comment: Your post made absolutely zero sense until I realized you were using parentheses instead of quotation marks. Where have you seen that? Why are you doing it? Please don't do it.

Answer (score 4):

No; the adjective *influential* applies to the person or thing that *exerts* the influence, not the person or thing *being* influenced:

> Having great influence on someone or something: 
> *her work is influential in feminist psychology* [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/influential?q=INFLUENTIAL&searchDictCode=all)]

For the meaning your friend seems to want, a good English expression might be something like “I follow your lead.”

Comment: To clarify for the OP, the sentence "I am influential of you" is saying that I influence you, not the other way around. It'd be more correct to say "you are influential of me," but that sounds funny.

Comment: As ODO's example suggests, though, the usual construction is with the preposition *on,* not *of.*

Comment: Yes, but most people don't say it like that anyway. It'd be better to say something like "you influence me."

Comment: I have found some websites that use "influential to" instead of "influential in". Can the former be accepted as grammatically correct as well?

Comment: *Influential in/of/to*: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=influential+in%2C+influential+of%2C+influential+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinfluential%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinfluential%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinfluential%20to%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Oops. Ngram and indeed the above ODO example favor *in,* above not only *of* and *to* but also *on.*

Answer (score 1):

[Influential](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/influential) is generally followed by ***in*** to refer to the level of influence on someone or something: (OLD)

> - having a lot of influence on somebody/something:
>
>   - *a highly influential book*

- ***influential in something***

> - *She is one of the most influential figures in local politics.*

- ***influential in doing something***

> - *The committee was influential in formulating government policy on employment.*

The preposition ***of*** is used to refer to  those who exert influence:

- The most famous and ***influential of*** the philosopher-scientists was...

Answer (score 0):

> I am influential **to** you

that would be the correct way to say it.